# Cannot send push notification using EXPO

Tags: push-notification, react-native, expo

I am trying to send a push notification using EXPO to my react native application but for some reason the phone is not receiving any notification.

My code looks as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Checklist from "./src/components/Checklist/Checklist";
import Main from "./src/components/Main/Main";
import Product from "./src/components/Product/Product";
import {Notifications,Permissions} from 'expo';

export default class AppContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
        notification: {},
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        registerForPushNotificationsAsync();

        // Handle notifications that are received or selected while the app
        // is open. If the app was closed and then opened by tapping the
        // notification (rather than just tapping the app icon to open it),
        // this function will fire on the next tick after the app starts
        // with the notification data.
        this._notificationSubscription = Notifications.addListener(this._handleNotification);
    }

    _handleNotification = (notification) => {
        this.setState({notification: notification});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Text>Origin: {this.state.notification.origin}</Text>
                <Text>Data: {JSON.stringify(this.state.notification.data)}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const PUSH_ENDPOINT = 'https://your-server.com/users/push-token';

async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
        Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
    );
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;

    // only ask if permissions have not already been determined, because
    // iOS won't necessarily prompt the user a second time.
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
        // Android remote notification permissions are granted during the app
        // install, so this will only ask on iOS
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
        finalStatus = status;
    }

    // Stop here if the user did not grant permissions
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
        return;
    }

    // Get the token that uniquely identifies this device
    let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
    console.log("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    console.log(token);

    // POST the token to your backend server from where you can retrieve it to send push notifications.
    return fetch(PUSH_ENDPOINT, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            token: {
                value: token,
            },
            user: {
                username: 'Brent',
            },
        }),
    });
}
```

I am trying to send notification thru https://expo.io/dashboard/notifications for testing purpose and suddently I read this:
Note: Expo push notifications are supported only in standard Expo projects. They are not supported in detached apps nor with create-react-native-app.

I was wondering if push notification of EXPO does not work for detached and apps created using **create-react-native-app**(in my case) what would this expo would work for?

Answer (score 1):

To use Push notifications, you'll need an Expo account and install `exp` command line.

See this: https://forums.expo.io/t/push-notifications-not-working-with-crna/858.

To understand the meaning of `standard CRNA app`, see this discussion: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/153

Comment: thanks for your reply, do you have any idea how or what command should I write to start a project in react native that supports push notifications and that does not require android studio or xcode to compile app as apk or ipa!

Answer (score -1):

For start project you have to go to you proyect folder from CMD.
In my case starting CMD i see C:\Users\Manuel . So.. i do this[Going to my proyect folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laR3z.png)

[For starting proyect do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWDJR.png)

[And for compiling do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niRkW.png)

Comment: This answer does not help the user with the problem with push notifications and is not relevant. If you have any relevant tips with push notifications please edit your question to include these please

Comment: My question was answering this: "do you have any idea how or what command should I write to start a project in react native that supports push notifications and that does not require android studio or xcode to compile app as apk or ipa!"